# Need help ending a while loop

Tags: python

So I'm having a problem where I can't figure out how to end a specific while loop.

```
one = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
thirty = [4, 6, 9, 11]

while True:
    try:
        month = int(input("Enter the number of the month: "))
    except month == "":
        print("Program ending")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")
        continue
    else:
        def days(month): 
            if month in one:
                return 31
            elif month in thirty:
                return 30
            elif month == 2:
                return 28
        
    if days(month) == None:
            print("The number has to be between 1-12")
    else:
        print("This month has", days(month) ,"days.")
```

So the program is supposed to tell you how many days are in the specified month and pretty much what I want to achieve is that the loop goes on and asks the question again until the user leaves a blank input (presses enter). I have searched google for quite some time but just can't seem to find the solution for my exact problem. I found out that you can't take the value of something in *except:* if the value was given in *try:*, which is the case in the code at the moment.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you really intend to define a function within your while loop? And having not called that function, it does nothing.

Comment: Well, I honestly don't know, I'm really new to programming and everything seemed to work except the fact that I can't end the loop. If you have any better suggestions then I'm open to those :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few little mistakes

As Chris said defining a function inside a while loop is of no use
so define the function above you while loop

Secondly you shouldnt try to convert your input to an int before chehing if its '' so you wont get a ValueError

Here is the code fixed

```
one = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
thirty = [4, 6, 9, 11]

def days(month):
    if month in one:
        return 31
    elif month in thirty:
        return 30
    elif month == 2:
        return 28


while True:
    month = input("Enter the number of the month: ")
    if month = '':
        print('program ending')
        break;
    try:
        month = int(month)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number")
        continue
    if days(month) == None:
        print("The number has to be between 1-12")
    else:
        print("This month has ", days(month), " days.")
```

Comment: Also take a look at @Lost_coder s answer its much more readable clean and performance wise better even tho this doesnt really matter here)

Answer (score 0):

Some comments regarding your code in general. You defined the input as an integer why would you even try to compare an integer with a string. You could do your string to int conversion a much later. Defining your function in a loop is not a good practice.

Also consider using switch statements or in python dictionaries when you need multiple if statements.

**Edit**

Catching a ValueError

Here is the adjusted code.

```py
months = {
    1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31,
    4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30,
    7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30,
    10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31
}

while True:
    month = input("Enter the number of the month: ")
    if month == "":
        print("Program ending")
        break
    try:
        month = int(month)
    except ValueError:
        print("please enter a number")

    if month in months.keys():
        print(months[month])
    else:
        print("not a month")
```

Comment: You should limit yourself to catching `ValueError`.